# Visual Studio News Channel When Using Proxy

Tags: visual-studio, proxy

Does anyone know how to force Visual Studio to use a proxy?

My VS install never shows any news on the front page as the company I work for uses a proxy

Any ideas??

This did not work - The XML addition was not correct and VS complained.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually set the proxy for Visual Studio. I've had this problem in the past with the integrated MSDN help (see [here](http://www.adrianbanks.co.uk/?p=15)). Try adding the following configuration into Visual Studio's config file (located inside the Visual Studio installation directory at `Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config`):

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
            <proxy bypassonlocal="True"
                   proxyaddress="http://yourproxy:port"/>
        </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried configuring the proxy settings in the Internet Properties? At least the Document Explorer uses the connection setting configured there

Open the **Internet Properties** from the windows control panel and select the tab **Connections**. There you click on the button **LAN settings** and setup your proxy.